# Hyperlink formula field open in new subtab of console

Tags: salesforce

I am able to open new console sub tab by below code with salesforce fourmula field.

```
HYPERLINK("javascript:if(typeof(srcUp)=='function') {srcUp('/apex/NSTK_SW_PeriodToPeriodFrom?scontrolCaching=1&id="&Id&"&isdtp=vw');}"+ " else {window.location.href='/apex/NSTK_SW_PeriodToPeriodFrom?scontrolCaching=1&id="&Id&"&isdtp=vw'}", "Reimbursement Statement", "_parent" )
```

but below I want to open below code in new subtab.... This is also a salesforce formula field with id instead of apex page which is the case above. This is opening in new tab of browser instead of console new tab.

```
HYPERLINK("/00O0j000000FNko?pv0="+Id,"Reimbursement Report","_blank")
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

try using "_self" in place of "_blank". This will open under same sub tab